# Content going over my header, but not footer?

Tags: html, css, header, position

My content in .box for some reason is going over my header, but not my footer when you resize the window. I was trying to make the footer/header fixed, so they don't move and have content go over them when the window is resized. But like I said it only works for the footer and the header allows content to go over it. So I'm wondering what can I do to fix this? Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: #323232;
  font-family: Lato;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.fixed-header{
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer{
  bottom: 0;
}

.box {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>

 <body>

<div class="fixed-header">
  <div class="container">
   <nav>
     <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
   </nav>
 </div>
</div>

  <div class="box">
  <div class="container">
   <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="" class="box-avatar">
   <h1>KUMO</h1>
   <h5>RANDOM DEVELOPER</h5>
   <ul>
     <li>I'm Kumo and this is my website. Here I post random releases of development, projects and concepts. Checkout my other pages for more information.</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fixed-footer">
    <div class="container"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2017</a></div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a `z-index` for the header with a higher number than the .box which are both `0` by default. So, like try `z-index: 999;` You can decide to set a higher z-index value for the footer too, although, as it is added after the .box element in the html layout, it will show on top by default.

```
.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, in the example, I decided to change the .box css. Not positive why you have the other css styles. Guess you were working on something a bit different.

```
.box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #323232;
  font-family: Lato;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.fixed-header{
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer{
  bottom: 0;
}

.box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 24px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>

 <body>

<div class="fixed-header">
  <div class="container">
   <nav>
     <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
   </nav>
 </div>
</div>

  <div class="box">
  <div class="container">
   <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="" class="box-avatar">
   <h1>KUMO</h1>
   <h5>RANDOM DEVELOPER</h5>
   <ul>
     <li>I'm Kumo and this is my website. Here I post random releases of development, projects and concepts. Checkout my other pages for more information.</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fixed-footer">
    <div class="container"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2017</a></div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help 'z-index' is what I needed, the website works fine now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    /* top: 50%; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Using these updated classes you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks also for the help, 'z-index' is what I needed, the website works fine now.  :)